# I have to stop debugging before building my C++ DLL project which has attached to a process in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2010, when I change the code in a C++ DLL project which has attached to a process, I can click "Build" to build the project without stopping debugging. However, it is not possible to do that in Visual Studio 2012: the message "Do you want to stop debugging?" will appear.

I've tested checking Edit and Continue in Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Does anyone know how to make the behavior in Visual Studio 2012 to be same as that in Visual Studio 2010?